# How to create new date format for datetime to use?

Tags: python, datetime, format, datetime-format

I am quite new to programming so please excuse if I don't use the correct terms.

I want to convert a list of dates into another format. Until now it was easy because the dates that I had to convert were in this format: %d-%b-%Y (example 13-Jan-2023). So I could just "tell" python that it was in this format and that it should convert it to : %d/%m/%Y (example 13/01/2023).

However, the initial date format has changed to 13-janv.-2023 (per example), so the months are now in french and abbreviated (janv. ; févr. ; mars ; avr. ; mai ; juin ; juil. ; sept. ; oct. ; nov. ; déc.

I can imagine that there must be a way to define a dictionary such as "Jan : janv. ", and then define it as a new format but I have not succeeded yet. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

I am sorry, I have not found a similar question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locale`is your friend for region-specific topics.

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import locale


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "fr_FR")
date_fr = '13-janv.-2023'
dt.strptime(date_fr, '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Returns your desired result. But be aware! After setting your locale, you can't parse your initial ('13-Jan-2023') format anyore until your change the locale back.

Explanation:
`strptime` is to *parse* your input, hence the *p* in the function name
`strftime` is to *format* your date/time, hence the *f*.